# I am trying to get the MFT Reference number for the $USNJRNL file. I have dumped the information but can't seem to parse out what I need to a variable

Tags: powershell

The output from the dump is RawCopy v1.0.0.22

Directory listing for: c:$Extend

Entry number: 1
FileName: $Deleted
MFT Ref: 29
MFT Ref SeqNo: 1
Parent MFT Ref: 11
Parent MFT Ref SeqNo: 0
Flags: hidden+system
File Create Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469
File Modified Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469
MFT Entry modified Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469
File Last Access Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469
Allocated Size: 0
Real Size: 0
NameSpace: POSIX
IndexFlags: 0000
SubNodeVCN:

Entry number: 2
FileName: $ObjId
MFT Ref: 25
MFT Ref SeqNo: 1
Parent MFT Ref: 11
Parent MFT Ref SeqNo: 0
Flags: hidden+system
File Create Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469
File Modified Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469
MFT Entry modified Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469
File Last Access Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469
Allocated Size: 0
Real Size: 0
NameSpace: POSIX
IndexFlags: 0000
SubNodeVCN:

Entry number: 3
FileName: $Quota
MFT Ref: 24
MFT Ref SeqNo: 1
Parent MFT Ref: 11
Parent MFT Ref SeqNo: 0
Flags: hidden+system
File Create Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469
File Modified Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469
MFT Entry modified Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469
File Last Access Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469
Allocated Size: 0
Real Size: 0
NameSpace: POSIX
IndexFlags: 0000
SubNodeVCN:

Entry number: 4
FileName: $Reparse
MFT Ref: 26
MFT Ref SeqNo: 1
Parent MFT Ref: 11
Parent MFT Ref SeqNo: 0
Flags: hidden+system
File Create Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469
File Modified Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469
MFT Entry modified Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469
File Last Access Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469
Allocated Size: 0
Real Size: 0
NameSpace: POSIX
IndexFlags: 0000
SubNodeVCN:

Entry number: 5
FileName: $RmMetadata
MFT Ref: 27
MFT Ref SeqNo: 1
Parent MFT Ref: 11
Parent MFT Ref SeqNo: 0
Flags: hidden+system
File Create Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469
File Modified Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469
MFT Entry modified Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469
File Last Access Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469
Allocated Size: 0
Real Size: 0
NameSpace: POSIX
IndexFlags: 0000
SubNodeVCN:

Entry number: 6
FileName: $UsnJrnl
MFT Ref: 78263
MFT Ref SeqNo: 3
Parent MFT Ref: 11
Parent MFT Ref SeqNo: 0
Flags: hidden+system+sparse_file
File Create Time: 2020-03-27 21:27:31:792:2895
File Modified Time: 2020-03-27 21:27:31:792:2895
MFT Entry modified Time: 2020-03-27 21:27:31:792:2895
File Last Access Time: 2020-03-27 21:27:31:792:2895
Allocated Size: 0
Real Size: 0
NameSpace: POSIX
IndexFlags: 0000
SubNodeVCN:

Job took 3.03 seconds

I am trying to only put '78263' into a variable so I can use it in a command. I am using PowerShell and have tried the following code but I can not get it to pull the string.

```
Get-Content 'e:filepath\file.txt'
```

I have also tried using Select-String but can not seem to get that to work either.

```
Select-String -Path "e:filepath\file.txt" -Pattern 'FileName: $UsnJrnl' -Context 0,1 | Out-File -FilePath 'e:filepath\file2.txt'
```

I can not seem to get that to work either. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using regular expressions on each line.

Since your input is from file rather than the section I hard-coded, you might want to exclude headers/blank lines before parsing.

I tried to keep it flexible so that you can easily get the other properties of values of other files by changing the regex.

For an explanation of the specific regex characters, plug them into a tool like https://regexr.com/

```
$Raw = @"
Entry number: 1 FileName: `$Deleted MFT Ref: 29 MFT Ref SeqNo: 1 Parent MFT Ref: 11 Parent MFT Ref SeqNo: 0 Flags: hidden+system File Create Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469 File Modified Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469 MFT Entry modified Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469 File Last Access Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469 Allocated Size: 0 Real Size: 0 NameSpace: POSIX IndexFlags: 0000 SubNodeVCN:
Entry number: 2 FileName: `$ObjId MFT Ref: 25 MFT Ref SeqNo: 1 Parent MFT Ref: 11 Parent MFT Ref SeqNo: 0 Flags: hidden+system File Create Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469 File Modified Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469 MFT Entry modified Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469 File Last Access Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469 Allocated Size: 0 Real Size: 0 NameSpace: POSIX IndexFlags: 0000 SubNodeVCN:
Entry number: 3 FileName: `$Quota MFT Ref: 24 MFT Ref SeqNo: 1 Parent MFT Ref: 11 Parent MFT Ref SeqNo: 0 Flags: hidden+system File Create Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469 File Modified Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469 MFT Entry modified Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469 File Last Access Time: 2020-03-27 22:25:39:560:2469 Allocated Size: 0 Real Size: 0 NameSpace: POSIX IndexFlags: 0000 SubNodeVCN:
Entry number: 6 FileName: `$UsnJrnl MFT Ref: 78263 MFT Ref SeqNo: 3 Parent MFT Ref: 11 Parent MFT Ref SeqNo: 0 Flags: hidden+system+sparse_file File Create Time: 2020-03-27 21:27:31:792:2895 File Modified Time: 2020-03-27 21:27:31:792:2895 MFT Entry modified Time: 2020-03-27 21:27:31:792:2895 File Last Access Time: 2020-03-27 21:27:31:792:2895 Allocated Size: 0 Real Size: 0 NameSpace: POSIX IndexFlags: 0000 SubNodeVCN:
"@ -split "`r?`n" #hardcoded raw data, you would have Get-Content here instead

$ParsedEntries = $Raw.ForEach{
    #?<MFT> names the match to avoid using index
    #[void] is to prevent the output from -match ($true in this case) entering the variable
    #$Matches is a special variable holding the results of -match
    [void]($_ -match 'FileName: (?<FileName>\S+).+ MFT Ref: (?<MFT>\S+)')
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Filename =  $Matches.FileName
        MFT =  $Matches.MFT
    }
}

$ParsedEntries.Where{$_.FileName -eq '$UsnJrnl'}
```

Comment: I think you'll want ```-split "`r?`n"``` (optional carriage return)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Agreed, but that section was just for mocking the data so it can be reproduced.

It wouldn't be in OP's actual code.

Comment: Well it's preventing your otherwise excellent example from actually working - try copy-pasting your code block into powershell :)

Comment: Ah I see. It works for me even when pasting back from web browser, but that's no excuse for being unix incompatible. Added

Comment: @OwlsSleeping So I plan on using this code for many different systems and the sequence numbers may never be the same in any system. One way that I have gotten to work is using Grep with powershell calling the grep.exe in windows to pull the two lines of code. If I could use that to just pull the information into a txt file I am sure that could in turn be used to fill a variable with get-content. The powershell that I used to call grep was '''grep -wns $UsnJrnl e:\filepath\file.txt -A 1''' That returns this 
92:FileName: $UsnJrnl
93-MFT Ref: 78263

Comment: I inturn out-file that into a .txt file. If I could use grep or something else to pull the 78263 into a file that would also work. So I can use Get-File to create the variable that I use to pull the $UsnJrnl FIle

Comment: Sorry for all the confusion, I do really appreciate the assistance.

Comment: @NonCoder I'm not seeing where the 92 comes from. If you want a random identifier you could use a guid, or if it's looping in a specific order you can use the iterator value, or filename, or computername etc.

For saving to file piping to export-csv or out-file should work here.

Comment: @OwlsSleeping the 92 is just garbage from how I grepped. I did not worry about it too much. I appreciate the assistance. I am going to get back to work on it more tomorrow, today is my birthday.

Comment: @OwlsSleeping 
I believe that the way to do this is with regex and PS. I am trying this command but it is barking at me for the *. I have tried '('*')' but that still does not work. Any suggestions?

((Get-Content -path 'e:file2.txt' -Raw) -replace '*','') | Set-Content -Path 'e:file2.txt'

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen please see above as well. I have tried everything that has been suggested more than likely it is a limitation of my understanding that is the issue. Not your assistance.

Comment: @NonCoder if you're trying to replace all asterisks, the regex escape character is "\". e.g. 'ab*' -replace '\\*', 'c' becomes abc. Feel free to raise another question or search other answers if this is going off-topic from your original query.

Comment: @OwlsSleeping so I ran the commands on several systems and it always output the 93. Not sure where it comes from but it ended up being easy to get what I wanted after I figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

With this, I ran three consecutive commands to finish the issue. It took the input above and output the correct sequence on about half a dozen systems. So I am happy. Thank you for your assistance it definitely steered me in the right direction.

'
((Get-Content -path "${output_dir}:\Triage$UsnJrnl${system_name}\junk\Log-${system_name}-grep-file2.txt" -Raw) -replace '93-MFT','') | Set-Content -Path "${output_dir}:\Triage$UsnJrnl${system_name}\junk\Log-${system_name}-grep-file2.txt"
((Get-Content -path "${output_dir}:\Triage$UsnJrnl${system_name}\junk\Log-${system_name}-grep-file2.txt" -Raw) -replace 'Ref: ','') | Set-Content -Path "${output_dir}:\Triage$UsnJrnl${system_name}\junk\Log-${system_name}-grep-file2.txt"
((Get-Content -path "${output_dir}:\Triage$UsnJrnl${system_name}\junk\Log-${system_name}-grep-file2.txt" -Raw) -replace ' ','') | Set-Content -Path "${output_dir}:\Triage$UsnJrnl${system_name}\junk\Log-${system_name}-grep-file2.txt"

$MFTREF1 = Get-Content "${output_dir}:\Triage$UsnJrnl${system_name}\junk\Log-${system_name}-grep-file2.txt"
'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).